# phpversion returns PHP version with extension name specified

Tags: php

I'm attempting to get the version of the cURL extension in my PHP environment. I haven't been able to find any solutions to this online anywhere.. I am passing the extension name `cURL` to the PHP function `phpversion();`. The function is returning the current PHP version (8.0.1).

Full line (Glorified echo/print statement):
`Debug::println(phpversion("cURL"));`

`curl_version();` returns `7.74.0`

I would prefer to use a standardized way, such as `phpversion();` of obtaining extension versions for environment requirements validation.

Comment: Does that extension name match that of `get_loaded_modules()`?

Comment: I matched it with the modules when used in `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);` Also tried `CURL `and `curl`. `get_loaded_extensions();` has cURL listed as `curl`

Comment: It seems kinda non-functional for almost all builtin modules.